# Python 'height' is not defined

Tags: python, variables, undefined, cs50, defined

Python is saying that the name 'height' is not defined, and I have no idea why that is, as according to my logic, I return the variable height, so I would be able to access it within my for loop?

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks. 
Edit: the get_int() is a function inside the cs50 library.

```
import cs50

def main():

    print("Enter a number between 0 and 26: ", end="")

    i = get_height("Enter height: ", end="")

def get_height():
    while True:
        height = get_int()
        if height <= 0 or height >= 23:
            break
    return height


for i in range(height):
    print(" " * (height - i), end="")
    print("#" * (i + 2), end="")
    print("")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Do you mean `for i in range(get_height())`? Returning height does not return the variable's name, it returns the value.

Comment: In other words, the name `height` in `get_height` is local to the `get_height` function, it has no connection to anything with that name outside the function. Also, `get_height` is being called in `main`, but `main` itself isn't being called until the very last line of the script.

Comment: Hello Jakob, this other question might be able to point you in the right direction.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do

Comment: @ForceBru My deepest apologies for my ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_int():
    tx = input("Enter height: ")
    if tx.isdigit():
        return int(tx)
    return None

def get_height():
    while True:
        height = get_int()
        if height and height > 0 and height < 26:
            return height


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Enter a number between 0 and 26: ")

    height = get_height()
    for i in range(height):
        print(" " * (height - i), end='')
        print("#" * (i + 2), end='')
        print("")
```

1. get_int doesn't exists
2. height was out of scope
3. height on the while loop was not visible from the def scope
4. get_height get no param
5. `for in range` was out of the main scope

Comment: Can you explain to me why when I try to run this, and enter a number, in the console, it just jumps to a new line and waits for some input it seems, nothing else happens.
Also, in your if statement, you say "if height and height" is that a typo or intentional? 
Thank you

Comment: @JakobHansen `input` is a built-in command to ask user for input. The the `if height` is because the `get_int` can return `None`, so we need to check.

Answer (score 0):

First, off you need to use `hight = raw_input("What is your hight")` to get your height. You can then use `int(height)` to use it as an integer. Secondly, you need to have it be top-down processing.